# C++ Iterator class

Tags: c++, class, iterator

```
class ZoningIter
{
private:
    CTile::Zonings mZoning;
    CCity *mCity;
    int mPos;       ///< Position in the collection

public:
    ZoningIter(CCity *tile, int pos, CTile::Zonings zoning) : mCity(tile), mPos(pos), mZoning(zoning) 
    {       
        while (mPos < mCity->mTiles.size())
        {
            if (mCity->mTiles[mPos]->GetZoning() == mZoning)
                break;
            else
                mPos++;
        }       
    }

    bool operator!=(const ZoningIter &other) const
    {
        return mPos != other.mPos;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<CTile> operator *() const
    {               
        return mCity->mTiles[mPos]; 
    }

    const ZoningIter& operator++()
    {                       
        auto size = mCity->mTiles.size();
        auto myzone = mCity->mTiles[mPos]->GetZoning();

        while (mPos < size-1)
        {
            ++mPos;
            if (mCity->mTiles[mPos]->GetZoning() == mZoning)
                break;
        }   
        return *this;           
    }
};
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong in this iterator. This class Iterator is suppose to loop over the class CCity and compare the tiles coming back with the ones that I am looking for.
one issue that I can see it run into an infinite  loop not sure how to fix it  ? any ideas?

Comment: I will just presume mTiles is a vector, then if you call the constructor with a pos that is greater than the size all *following* operations on the iterator will blow up. Also any change to the vector like deleting an element will (potentially) make it blow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into an infinite loop because your `operator++` won't increment to one past all elements, also known as an end-iterator.

```
while (mPos < size-1) // <-- This line is wrong, stops too early
```

It masks the error in the check-for-success you do afterwards.

Anyway, it should start with an increment, and then check whether it can and should loop.
A corrected version, with both bugs removed:

```
const ZoningIter& operator++() {
    while( ++mPos < mCity->mTiles.size()
        && mCity->mTiles[mPos]->GetZoning() != mZoning)
        {}
    return *this;
}
```

Also, the return-type of `operator*()` should be `const std::shared_ptr<CTile>&`, the caller can make a copy if needed.